# how to install and run SQLite or SQL on a Mac?

Tags: sqlite

i am trying to install and run SQLite or SQL on my mac. I installed the application, but it's not giving me the option to run it. It says its not compatible with the developer. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! =)  Stack overflow is unique among forum sites for being fairly stringent on the types of questions that are considered good quality:  They should be specific and detailed.  Right now, your question is lacking a bit of detail.  If you could include more detail about how exactly you tried to install it, which of the programs you ended up trying (mySQL, SQLite etc.), and what your error message was and where you got it.  It would greatly improve the quality of your question.  It also might pay to do a bit more googling about the issue before posting. Best of luck!

Comment: A cursory google search brought up this article: https://blog.joefallon.net/2013/10/install-mysql-on-mac-osx-using-homebrew/ which may or may not be helpful.

Comment: You can't install "SQL" - that's just a query language, not a specific database product. Every relational database uses SQL - so just install any of the relational database and you have "SQL" installed. PostgreSQL is a good choice

Comment: Thank you all really appreciate it. This was very helpful

Answer (score 2):

SQLite is already installed on the Mac.  Go to Terminal create a directory e.g. sqlite by typing Mkdir sqlite, next type cd sqlite, now type sqlite3 mytest.db.
You should see something like: SQLite version 3.19.3 2017-06-27 16:48:08.  The prompt will also change to sqlite>, type .help for a list of commands.  I hope this helps.